# how to remove element in array object

Tags: javascript

array :
array before
[ { id: 1, test: [ null, 2, 3 ] }, { id: 2, test: [ 1, 2, 3 ] } ]

array after
[ { id: 1, test: [ 2, 3 ] }, { id: 2, test: [ 1, 2, 3 ] } ]
how to remove value null?

I have tried with this function but it doesn't work what is wrong with this functionl in array?

```
var filtered = fullArray.filter(function (object) {
    return object.test !== null;
  });
```

Comment: An array is obviously `!== null`

Comment: `fullArray.map(i => ({ ...i, test: test.filter(j => j !== null) }))`

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop over your nested array and apply `filter` on it instead of comparing it to `null`

```js
const fullArray = [{
  id: 1,
  test: [null, 2, 3]
}, {
  id: 2,
  test: [1, 2, 3]
}]


var filtered = fullArray.map(function(obj) {
  return ({
    ...obj,
    test: obj.test.filter(elm => elm)
  })
});

console.log(filtered)
```

Explanation:

This first "outer" map is iterating over your array elements, taking each element (`obj`) and returning something

```
var filtered = fullArray.map(function(obj) {
  ...
});
```

The returning value:

```
return ({
    ...obj,
    test: obj.test.filter(elm => elm)
  })
```

Is a copy of `obj` made with [the spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals), with an override of our `test` attribute which will contain the outputs from the `obj.test.filter(elm => elm)` method.

[`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is a method that iterates over an array and returns the element only if a given predicate (a function that returns a boolean) returns true. In our case, if the `test` array item is `null` means that it's `false`, and then it will be removed from the array.

Comment: This doesn't give the desired output.

Comment: Sorry I missed the spread operator, just fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest with two **simple** ways :

```js
let fullArray = [ { id: 1, test: [ null, 2, 3 ] }, { id: 2, test: [ 1, 2, 3 ] } ];

// first way
let filtered = fullArray.map(m => ({
  id: m.id, 
  test: m.test.filter(f => f !== null)
}));

console.log(filtered);

// second way
fullArray.forEach((fe) => {
  fe.test = fe.test.filter(f => f !== null);
  return fe;
});

console.log(fullArray);
```